# Add ControlTemplate to AnimatedTabControl without overwriting animation behavior

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps **AnimatedTabControl** and I need to create a **ControlTemplate** to add a ScrollViewer for header tabs. Here is my template:

```
     <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="_MainTabControlScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="4" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>
```

However, this kills the animation. Is there a way to inherit the default AnimatedTabControl behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Instead overriding the `TabControl` just use the `MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl`.

```
<Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl x:Name="AnimatedTabControl">
  <TabItem Header="tab test"></TabItem>
</Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

with `xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I suspect this is because there is another ControlTemplate to wrap my Grid inside the <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Template